# How can I sum rows when the date and the province is the same in R studio?

Tags: r, group-by, sum, aggregate

How can I sum the rows with the same date and province? I want 1 row instead of multiple with the same date and province.

**Snapshot:**
[image]

Comment: Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to write a good question regarding R.

Comment: Take a look at [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)